# Making users Active and In-Active

Tags: c#

This worked one time. and one time only, I've restarted the program and still nothing. I've also tried to do the exact opposite, which was making users Active from Inactive status.. same exact code just instead of False, it was True.  And i dont know why it's all of a sudden not making users In-Active. Is there a delay of data from my program to salesforce and back to my program? I wrote my code in C#, a Windows form using Visual Studio 2013. No idea whats going on. Anyone have any input?

```
        QueryResult queryResult = null;
        String SOQL = "";
        SOQL = "select Id, IsActive from user where isactive = true";
        queryResult = Sfdcbinding.query(SOQL);

        string UserId = null;
        bool? active = false;

        if (rdbYes.Checked == true)
        {
            RevokeLicense();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.size; i++)
        {
            User user = (User)queryResult.records[i];
            UserId = user.Id;              

            if (lblUserID.Text == UserId && chkActive.Checked == false)
            {
                User userChange = new User();
                userChange.IsActive = active;
                try
                {
                    SaveResult[] saveResults = Sfdcbinding.update(new sObject[] { userChange });                                                                       
                }
                catch (SoapException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error has occurred: " +
                                  e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        lstEditUser.Items.Clear();
        CallAllQueries();
```

Comment: What does `RevokeLicense()` do? Are you reversing that as well. Also, you would need to modify the SOQL query where clause for `isactive = true` if you were trying to reactivate users.

Comment: @DanielBallinger You're right, i Would have to modify it to Isactive = true for reactivating users. The SOQL Query has nothing to do with it though, thats just to get the user id and match it so i dont delete the wrong user.  The revoke license just deletes a users License that cost our company money at the same time i'm deactivating a user so that there arnt extra licenses being used that we're paying for.  It's just an extra step. Like i said, this worked once, and hasnt worked since.

Comment: Have you verified that calls to update are actually occurring and that the `SaveResult` is successful? There is a `success` property to check and `errors` if something went wrong. Incidentally, you should collect all the updates up and make one call to `update` rather than a seperate call per User. You don't need to query the User if you have the Id. Just create an sObject and set the Id.

Comment: @DanielBallinger So, i did the error messsage. and it didnt have an ID to update when doing SaveResults.. how ever, gave it an ID, and it's still not updating the user.